# iOS: generate random array between a specific range

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array with 80 objects of json. I want to build a new subarray that has only 4 elements(but different everytime filled from the bigger array of 80 elements) with only a particular key of that json.

Following is my code for this:

```
[arr_sub removeAllObjects];
    [arr_sub addObject:[[arr_main objectAtIndex:currentcount] valueForKey:@"e"]];
    for(int i =1;i<=3;i++)
    {
       //int random = number between 1 to 80 -- how do i generate this ??
        [arr_sub addObject:[[arr_main objectAtIndex:random] valueForKey:@"e"]];
    }
```

How do I generate a random index between 0 to 79?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a random index in a range use `arc4random_uniform(range)`.
In your case:

```
int random = arc4random_uniform(80);
```

Use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of `arc4random()`, it does not have a bias as with using the mod operator. Also never use the C function `rand()` because it's result is not random.

But where is the JSON? JSON is a transport representation, in Objective-C the main collection classes are `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Received JSON is converted into a combination of these usually with the class `NSJSONSerialization` and a method such as:

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 2):

`arc4random()` Will generate random number between 0-1, U can use it like this:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 80;

int randNum = arc4random() % (max - min) + min;
```

Comment: Instead use `arc4random_uniform()`, it is simpler and does not have a bias as with using the mod operator.

Comment: If the range is 10-100 (min != 0)?

Comment: `arc4random(max - min) + min`

Comment: The % operand is so bad?

Comment: So bad, for small ranges: no. But why when `arc4random_uniform()` is available, simpler to use and has no bias? Why pick an inferior method?

Answer (score 1):

arc4random is the function using which you can generate the random numbers.

```
int randomNumber = arc4random()%80;
```

Comment: Instead use `arc4random_uniform()`, it is simpler and does not have a bias as with using the mod operator.